# FBD of 4Kg block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

In this diagram when we draw FBD of the 4Kg block will we write the force by earth (weight) as 4 kg or 10 kg .I believe it should be 10 as when FBD is drawn it should also contain wt. Of 6kg block as it is connected to it and underneath it but I may be wrong. Can somebody please clarify the doubt.

[enter link description here][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa43H.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are combining the forces already. For the block of mass = 4kg, there are three forces acting on it: 1) the force of gravity, 2) the tension of the string between it and the 6kg block, and 3) the tension of the string between it and the 2kg block. What you are proposing is to combine forces 1 and 2, which is valid in the sense that they are always in the same direction, but most likely you will need to keep separated to eventually eliminate the tension force that will appear in the FBD of the 6kg block.

Comment: So essentially while making the FBD we will write wt. as 4kg only right?@Alonso

Comment: @gucci, that's right.